# getting notice in php file while executing

Tags: php, javascript

what is the meaning of undefined property DOMElement::$node Vaoue

I searched in google I didn't get any annswer for this.

Comment: Please post the code which causes this issue.

Comment: Perhaps a typo in the word 'Vaoue', changing it to 'Value' might help.

In general, you need to put detail into your question, what are you trying to do? attach relevant code? etc. Take a look at some of the other question on here.

Comment: Thank you. I got the output. you absolutly right.

Answer (score 2):

**what is the meaning of undefined property DOMElement::$node Vaoue**

It simple means that you have a undefined property DOMElement in your code.

To Help you in details we realy like to se more from the code which causes the error

Answer (score 0):

Well, a good start would be to post the code you're trying to execute. Anyways most likely, a property you're trying to access is undefined.